# How many equivalence relations there are on a set with 7 elements with some conditions

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

> Calculate how many equivalence relations there are on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \}$ that include the set $\{(2,2),(1,3),(3,6),(7,5)\}$ and are foreign to the set $\{(1,7),(4,7),(4,3)\}$.

Well I first drew a matrix, highlighted the wanted pairs and crossed the unwanted ones, I realise for example that if we want $(1,3)$ then $(3,1)$ must be included as well. Now partitioning them by hand is extremely tedious and I doubt that's what I'm supposed to do.

I also found out about Bell numbers from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676519/how-many-equivalence-relations-on-a-set-with-4-elements) which we don't even cover in this course but I'm not sure how to use it since there are six pairs that must always be excluded and eight that must be included.

How am I supposed to approach this ?

Comment: "I first drew...I doubt that's what I'm supposed to do." Indeed, Bell is better!

Comment: @MattAllegro how do you do it with Bell then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inclusion condition implies there is an equivalence class $A$ containing $\{1,3,6\}$ and a class $B$ containing $\{5,7\}$.  The fact that $1$ and $7$ are *not* equivalent means $A\not=B$.  Furthermore, the fact that $4$ is not equivalent to either $7$ or $3$ means there is a third equivalence class $C$ containing $\{4\}$.  The remaining element, $2$, can be in any of these three classes, or could constitute its own class, $D$.  Thus there are four different equivalence relations satisfying the two conditions.

Note that the inclusion condition on $(2,2)$ is irrelevant, since equivalence requires each number to be equivalent to itself.

Comment: Surely I could make more than four partitions that satisfy the conditions. What about all the other combinations with other pairs?

Comment: @kuhaku, it may seem that way, since the Bell number for $7$ is fairly large, but every time you add a condition saying "this is equivalent to that" or "this is *not* equivalent to that," it cuts the number of possibilities down considerably.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how you chose the equivalence classes and why the amount of equivalence classes is the same as the amount of legal relations ?

Also, how can it be done with on a set like $\{1,2,3,4\}$ with no conditions ?